# Java SWT: Composite vs Shell

Tags: java, swt

In a Java SWT lab I had previously, it talks about using Composites then adding the `main()`

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    Calculator calc = new Calculator(shell, SWT.NONE);
    calc.pack();
    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while(!shell.isDisposed()){
            if(!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
}
```

But why do it this way. Shouldn't I use a Shell? What might be the reasons for this?

Comment: Your question is unclear: First, what is this Calculator class? Second: A `Shell` is used (see line 3). What do you mean with your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your question is why you should extend `Composite` and shouldn't extend `Shell`? Well, you can use any approach you want. But, if you put your stuff directly into the shell, it is going to be much harder to reuse this code in some other place. E.g. using `Composite` as base class for your components, allows you to make your code more reusable (you can't really put a Shell in the middle of another Composite).

Comment: The [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/package-summary.html) is clear - `Shell`: _IMPORTANT: This class is not intended to be subclassed._ `Composite`: _This class may be subclassed by custom control implementors who are building controls that are constructed from aggregates of other controls._